# C++- Adding or subtracting '0' from a value

Tags: c++

I was looking at the code below and I got the logic but I cannot seem to understand what is the use of `'0'`.

```
class Solution
{
public:
    string addBinary(string a, string b)
    {
        string s = "";

        int c = 0, i = a.size() - 1, j = b.size() - 1;
        while(i >= 0 || j >= 0 || c == 1)
        {
            c += i >= 0 ? a[i --] - '0' : 0;
            c += j >= 0 ? b[j --] - '0': 0;
            s = char(c % 2 + '0') + s;
            c /= 2;
        }

        return s;
    }
};
```

Comment: It seems for converting between integers and digit characters.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if I do + '0' or - '0' they both give the same result?

Comment: No, `+'0'` is integer -> character, `'-'0'` is character -> integer

Comment: Oh I see!! Thats something new to me! Thank you buddy!

Comment: `'1' - '0'` is `1`, `'2' - '0'` is `2` and `'3' - '0'` is `3`. Besides, `'0' + 1` is `'1'`, `'0' + 2` is `'2'` and `'0' + 3` is `'3'`.

Comment: Note that `'0'` is not zero. It's a character literal whose integer value is implementation defined (but in ASCII has the decimal value 48. That's why there's a difference between `c + '0'` and `c - '0'`... The `'0'` itself doesn't have an integer value of zero.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C and C++ standards require that the characters `'0'..'9'` be contiguous and increasing. So to convert one of those characters to the digit that it represents you subtract `'0'` and to convert a digit to the character that represents it you add `'0'`.

Answer (score 4):

C++ requires ([lex.charset]/3) that, in the basic character set, the numerals `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, ..., `'9'` are encoded as contiguous values. That means that given a numeral character `c`, you can compute its integral value as the expression `c - '0'`.

Answer (score 1):

The value '0' represent offset of ascii table for numeric character representation.
To compare two values when one is ascii and another is binary you need to convert to same base representation.

Comment: No, the value `'0'` represents the character '0' in whatever encoding the compiler uses. That is often ASCII, but it is not required to be. There are other encodings.

Answer (score 1):

In ASCII code character 0, represented as '0' in C (and many other languages) has the value 48. Also in ASCII the other 9 numerals are contiguous: '0', '1', etc.
A string is composed of characters. So if you subtract '0' to another numeral you get its numeric value.

Comment: No, the value '0' represents the character '0' in whatever encoding the compiler uses. That is often ASCII, but it is not required to be. There are other encodings.

Comment: Thank you, and you are correct, but I think that your comment shouldn't start the way you start it. Please see the beginning of my sentence.