# I don't understand the process converting string to int

Tags: c++

Given the following code.
this problem is Leet Code 415.

```
string addStrings(string num1, string num2) {
        
        string res;
        int sum = 0;
        int i = num1.size() - 1;
        int j = num2.size() - 1;
        
        
        while(i >= 0 && j >= 0)
        {
            sum += (num1[i--] - '0') + (num2[j--] - '0'); // this problem point
            res.push_back(char(sum%10 + '0'));
            sum = sum/10;
        }
        
        while(i >= 0)
        {
            sum += (num1[i--] - '0');
            res.push_back(char(sum%10 + '0'));
            sum = sum/10;
        }
        
        while(j >= 0)
        {
            sum += (num2[j--] - '0');
            res.push_back(char(sum%10 + '0'));
            sum = sum/10;
        }
        
        if(sum > 0)
            res.push_back(char(sum%10 + '0'));
        reverse(res.begin(), res.end());
        
        return res;
    }
```

I don't understand the process converting string to int.
Why is it a int when I subtract '0' from string?
If it doesn't change int, how is it possible to operate on strings?

Comment: `num1[i--]` is (in essence) a `char`. So is `'0'`. Both are integer types

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406076/subtract-letters-in-python) This might help to understand, how you can subtract chars

Comment: '0' = [integer value 48](https://www.asciitable.com/). 0 = integer value 0. Subtracting '0' is subtracting 48, giving the integer value that the character actually represents.

Comment: duplicate: [C++- Adding or subtracting '0' from a value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37683200/995714), [What does '0' mean in a subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59911398/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c++ characters can be implicitly cast to integers using their ASCII codes. I don't really want to spoil the fun of solving the given problem so i'll just provide a hint here:
Given a single digit number '2' and '4' with an ASCII code of 50 and 52 (decimal) respectively, subtracting '0' with an ASCII code of 48 from both numbers, you get the actual numerical values of the characters (50-48 = 2) and so on.
Have fun coding!

Comment: They aren't implicitly cast, but rather are integer types. See:https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#1

Comment: @Lala5th `char` is not an integer type. It *is* an integral type. And `char` used as an arithmetic operand is indeed implicitly converted to `int` before the operation. "Implicit cast" is self-contradictory though since cast is an *explicit* conversion.

Comment: @eerorika I literally linked the standard: "There are five standard signed integer types: “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int [...] For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) standard unsigned integer type: “unsigned char”, “unsigned short int”, “unsigned int”, “unsigned long int”, and “unsigned long long int" [...] Type char is a distinct type that has an implementation-defined choice of “signed char” or “unsigned char”"

Comment: @Lala5th And that list literally doesn't contain `char`. That said, I'll have to retract my claim though, since integral type is apparently synonym for integer type.

Comment: @eerorika I included the part where it does say that `char` is implementation defined for `unsigned char` or `signed char`, both being on the list

Comment: @Lala5th You cut off the rest of the sentence "... as its underlying type.". Just because `char` is implemented with underlying type being one of those, it isn't either of those types, and those types being signed and unsigned integer types has no effect on `char` being in those categories, and it isn't. But Like I said, I've retracted my claim, since I found out that char is indeed an integer type because that's a synonym for integral type.

Comment: @Lala5th Pointing back to the same link that's provided about the standard, both of you are correct it seems. https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#11
Thanks for the information!

Comment: `In c++ characters can be implicitly cast to integers using their ASCII codes` C++ doesn't say anything about encoding. EBCDIC or any other encodings are also allowed

Answer (score 3):

So the way [ascii](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) works is that consecutive numbers are following each other. If a string of characters only contain digits, you can get those digits by subtracting the value `'0'` from them. In ascii `'0' = 0x30`, `'1' = 0x31` etc..

In your code `num[i--] - '0'` just checks "how far" you are from `'0'` in the ascii table, giving the correct digit if it is indeed a digit.

Also you don't convert string to anything (at least on the specific line). You access an element, which is a `char` that is an integer type in c++.

Comment: EBCDIC also works that way, but the digits are in a different zone.

Comment: C++ doesn't require ASCII. Any encoding is allowed as long as `'0'` to `'9'` is a continuous sequence